# Some function keys stop working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have some problem with my built in (also externeal) keybord.
Function keys (volume up/down, mute) and polish characters (right alt) are not working anymore. Right alt behave in the same way as left alt (open HUD). I also can't entry polish characters with Onboard (on screen keyboard).

What I tried:

- Function keys are correctly configured in `system settings->keyboard->shortcuts`, system see them correctly (I tried to change this and I am able to do it)
- There is polish keyboard layout selected 
   [image]

Anybody have idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I partially resolved this issue (polish characters are working)

I ran `ibus-setup` and manually selected polish on `entry setup` page

Answer (score 0):

It's a trick to refresh your input system by Change the Option in *Universal Access*.

Just enable or disable the option *On Screen Keyboard* in *Universal Access*. It may be make sense.