# Alternative characters key doesn't work after restarting Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, special-characters

After restarting my laptop the Alternative Characters Key doesn't work. Although it is set as Right Alt I can't enter Polish characters such as "ł,ó,ą,ę,ż,ź,ć,ń" using it. I always have to go to `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Typing` and there I just have to change any one of the shortcuts to something else (for example 'disabled') for a moment and then set it again to the previous value. This is really unexpected but after this typing works fine, however it drives me mad that I have to do it every time I start my laptop!

The problem may have started when I installed Wine and a game 'Heroes of Might and Magic III' but I'm not sure. It may as well have begun when I installed some other programmes for Ubuntu such as audio-recorder or  lmms. I have tried removing all the recently installed programs including wine but nothing solved the problem. Please, help!

Comment: I had similar issue with Chinese.  I had to install it through Language Support in settings

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case changing system language to Polish in Language Support doesn't help.

Comment: @geras did you find out where was a problem? I have very this same problem :(

Comment: For anyone reading this - noisy found the solution which is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/426930/92413) I found solution, which works for me.

Type in console `ibus-setup`, and then make sure, that you have following settings:
[image]
[image]
[image]

To avoid different problems with switching beetwen Polish and English, I removed English from list.

[image]

Proof: u mnie działa świetnie :)

Comment: Thanks, you're great!
It turned out what I needed to do was just to remove English from this list. (no need to change to Dvorak layout)